# how to get ppp interface gateway address in debain 6?

Tags: linux, ppp

I am using debain 6 and using a Sierra modem c888 to connect internet. I am using wvdial package for connecting the modem. I am able to connect internet. The question I have is, how do get the gateway address of the newly created ppp0 interface? The following is the output of my wvdial connect command.

```
$wvdial --conf=wvdial.conf CONNECT
--> WvDial: Internet dialer version 1.60
--> Cannot get information for serial port.
--> Initializing modem.
--> Sending: ATZ
OK
--> Sending: AT!BAND=00
OK
--> Sending: AT+CGDCONT=16,"IP","airtelgprs.com"
OK
--> Modem initialized.
--> Sending: ATDT*99***16#
--> Waiting for carrier.
CONNECT 7200000
--> Carrier detected.  Starting PPP immediately.
--> Starting pppd at Fri Jun 10 05:37:27 2011
--> Pid of pppd: 5501
--> pppd: ��d[08]�Oe[08]�}e[08]
--> Using interface ppp0
--> pppd: ��d[08]�Oe[08]�}e[08]
--> pppd: ��d[08]�Oe[08]�}e[08]
--> pppd: ��d[08]�Oe[08]�}e[08]
--> pppd: ��d[08]�Oe[08]�}e[08]
--> pppd: ��d[08]�Oe[08]�}e[08]
--> pppd: ��d[08]�Oe[08]�}e[08]
--> local  IP address 27.61.17.87
--> pppd: ��d[08]�Oe[08]�}e[08]
--> remote IP address 10.64.64.64
--> pppd: ��d[08]�Oe[08]�}e[08]
--> primary   DNS address 202.56.230.5
--> pppd: ��d[08]�Oe[08]�}e[08]
--> secondary DNS address 202.56.230.6
--> pppd: ��d[08]�Oe[08]�}e[08]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to parse the output of the `route` command after the connection is established :

```
route | grep ppp0 | awk '{print $2}'
```

the `$2` is the gateway address :)